# Is there any similar verb negation in other Indo-European languages?

Tags: indo-european, negation, indo-aryan

In the northern part of Iran, in Mazandaran, we negate like this (this is the only verb being used like this as far as I'm aware of):

```
bɜtʊ̈ndɜ: he/she can
bætʊ̈ndɜ: he/she can't
```

is there anything like it in other Indo-European languages?

edit:
another example can be:

```
bænʃɜnɜ --> Persian: nɜmɪʃævæd   meaning "it is not possible (to happen)"
bɜnʃɜnɜ --> Persian:   mɪʃævæd   meaning "it is possible (to happen)"
```

Comment: Apophonic morphology is common.

Comment: i thought in most indoeuropian languages "n" sound or a variation of it indicates negation.

Comment: @amegnunsen: This is not apophony (alias Ablaut), at least not in the sense of that word in IE studies.

Comment: @shetal If your question is restricted to negation, so I am not aware of that. But, apophony, as a morphological process, is very common in IE. In Riffian, there is smth like this, but it is in combination with other markers (e.g. icca/he ate >>> ur icci ci/he didn't eat).

Comment: @fdb Can you enlighten me?

Comment: @amegnunsen I solely mean the negation matter.what I'm saying is that at least (as far as I know of course) this kind of negation is not present in any other neo-Iranian language. and I'm extremely curious about the origin of it.

Comment: Could it be two unrelated roots, cp (though unrelated) Fr *bon, bien* "good, well" vs *ban-* "banned" (viz *banlieu*), that somehow converged du to euphonie in this word?

Comment: @vectory I don't think so.they are the same. from per. "tævaan": "power, energy, having the ability of".then the form changed to "tʊ̈n" in the language/dialect I mentioned above.

Comment: I thought your question was about the prefixes

Comment: @vectory .well it is.man... I think I have a serious problem when it comes to conveying something.in the latter comment, I'm saying the roots of this dialect and Persian are the same but the negation is absolutely different from any Indo-European languages I've ever seen or heard of.

Comment: In American English the modal verb _can_ is usually pronounced /kɛn/, while the negative contraction _can't_ is usually pronounced /kæn/. There may be a /t/ after /kæn/ or there may not; but it's the vowel change that signals the negation. _He **can** do it_ and _He **can't** do it_ (with emphatic stress) are a minimal pair, differing  only in /ɛ ~ æ/

Comment: @jlawler well don't know if that's a root feature of English or not (ie if it was present in old English) and Mazandarani or its former name Tapuri or Tabari is much closer to European languages than Persian in SOME aspects. like: mzn: moong , eng: moon , per: maah.

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you are saying is that for this one verb the negative form changes the vowel of the prefix from /ɜ/ to /æ/. Is that right? These correspond to classical Persian bi-tawānad     بتواند and na-bi-tawānad نبتواند respectively. I am not familiar with this construction in any other language.

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I'm saying.and what I'm curious is how this kind of grammar came to being. is it an evolved form of Iranian grammar or it dates back before the Aryans intermingled with northern people.

Comment: @shetal: One could imagine a proto-form with *na-bi-, then assimilation of the second vowel to the first, giving *na-ba-, and then loss of the negative particle, giving ba-, contrasting with the unassimilated bi- of the positive form.